# How can I convert a Group By series to a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { 
"Name" : ["Bob", "Bryan", "Bob", "Bryan" , "Bryan"] , 
"Value" : [10,20,15,50,45] } )
```

Then I got the minimum value per person:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Name"])["Value"].min()
```

This is quite simple. However, I want to keep working with dataframes, but df1 is a serie:

```
type(df1)
```

How can I convert it to a dataframe again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `as_index=False` in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Name"],as_index=False)["Value"].min()
```

Or add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(["Name"])["Value"].min().reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
    Name  Value
0    Bob     10
1  Bryan     20
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use [agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) which return a dataframe.

```
df1 = df.groupby("Name").agg({'Value': 'min'}).reset_index()
```